# Is there any way to customize NuGet package update?

Tags: nuget

I've created nuget package with code transformation.
My package contains several source files (which is necessary for correct package integration).
But if package user decides to rename some files that comes with package (which is normal situation), then during package update this files will be re-created. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not unless your write some crazy logic in powershell. NuGet doesn't handle updates to source files well if the user changes them in anyway.